# Showing V is finite dimensional if there is a linear map $T$ on $V$ such that $\ker T$ and range $T$ are finite dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

[There are a couple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738968/if-rankt-and-nullt-are-finite-prove-that-dimv-is-finite) other [answers for this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220528/if-tv-to-w-is-such-that-both-kert-and-operatornameimt-are-finite) here, but I'm actually looking for a proof verification (or really a foot foward for my own take in a different direction as the others).

My proof (so far):

Choose a basis $u_1,\dots,u_n$ of range $T$. Then for $v\in V$, we have $Tv=\lambda_1u_1+\dots+\lambda_n u_n$. Since $Tv\in$ range $T\subseteq V$, we have that $Tv$, an arbitrary element in $V$, is written in terms of a basis of range $T$, which is finite.

Assuming this is correct, what does it tell us about $\dim V$? A better question might be: is it possible to move on in the right direction from here?

My tired self wants to say that we would have $V=$ range $T$ (implying $\dim \ker T=0$ i.e. $T$ injective?), but I also feel like that's... wrong, to say the least.

Comment: Do you think $V / \ker T$ is bijective with the image of $T$?  You seem to be moving in that direction.

Comment: Actually, while we learned that earlier this semester, I'm going back through homework and at this point in the book, V/ker T (assuming you mean a quotient space) hasn't been introduced yet.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to move on in the correct direction, if you adjust things slightly.

Choose a basis $Tu_1,\ldots, Tu_n$ of the range, $T$. Then for $v\in V$ we have $Tv=\lambda_1Tu_1+\cdots + \lambda_nTu_n=T(\lambda_1u_1+\cdots+\lambda_nu_n)$.

Therefore $Tv-T(\lambda_1u_1+\cdots+\lambda_nu_n) = T(v-\sum_i \lambda_iu_i)= 0$.
And so $(v-\sum_i\lambda_iu_i)\in\ker T$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: The last line implies that $v=\sum\lambda_i u_i$. We know that $\lambda_1u_1,\dots,\lambda_n u_n$ is linearly independent. Does it follow that it spans $V$, and is thus a basis of $V$ itself?

Comment: @jaska, that's not quite right. The last line is that $v-\sum_i\lambda_iu_i \in\ker T$, it only implies $v=\sum_i\lambda_iu_i$ if $\ker T =\{0\}$. All we know is that $\ker T$ is finite dimensional. Say it has basis $w_j$. Then we know that $v-\sum_i\lambda_iu_i =\sum_j\mu_jw_j$. Then $v=\sum_i\lambda_iu_i+\sum_j\mu_jw_j$.

Comment: Then $v$ is in the span of the set $\{u_i\}\cup\{w_j\}$. Hence $V$ is spanned by a finite set, and is finite dimensional.

Comment: Couldn't we use the fact from my post that since $Tv$ is written in terms of a basis of range $T$, then $Tv\in span(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ means that an arbitrary value in $V$ is in the spanning set of a finite dimensional subspace?

Comment: @jaska Honestly that's kind of what's going on in my post. You were missing some steps before because you were leaving out the degrees of freedom in $V$ that come from being able to move around in the kernel before taking the linear transformation.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I saw, but what I mean is: do you have to even touch the kernel? By showing that an arbitrary member of $V$ is represented as a basis of a finite dimensional subspace, isn't that enough?

Comment: @jaska, but you haven't done that, you showed $Tv$ could be written in that form, not that $v$ could.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\beta=\{u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_m\}$ be a basis for ${\rm range}(T)$ and 
$\gamma=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ be a basis for ${\rm ker}(T)$. Then we may write
$u_i=Tw_i$ for some $w_i\in V$, where $1\le i\le m$. Now, it suffices to claim that
\begin{align}
\alpha=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n,w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_m\}
\end{align}
is a basis for $V$.

1. Given $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$ and $b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m$ be scalars such that
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i+\sum_{j=1}^mb_jw_j={\it 0}.\tag{1}
   \end{align}
   Then
   \begin{align}
   {\it 0}
   &=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i+\sum_{j=1}^mb_jw_j\right)\\
   &=\sum_{i=1}^na_iTv_i+\sum_{j=1}^mb_jTw_j\\
   &=\sum_{j=1}^mb_ju_j,
   \end{align}
   which follows that $b_j=0$ for each $j$ because $\beta$ is a basis for ${\rm range}(T)$. Thus equation $(1)$ becomes $\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i={\it 0}$,
   but since $\gamma$ is a basis for ${\rm ker}(T)$, we must have $a_i=0$ for each $i$. Hence $\alpha$ is linearly independent.
2. Given $v\in V$, then $Tv\in{\rm range}(T)$ and we can write 
   $Tv=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iTw_i=T\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iw_i\right)$
   for some scalars $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_m$. It follows that
   $$T\left(v-\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iw_i\right)=Tv-T\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iw_i\right)={\it 0},$$
   that is, $v-\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iw_i\in{\rm ker}(T)$. Thus we can write 
   $v-\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iw_i=\sum_{j=1}^n\mu_jv_j$ for some scalars
   $\mu_1,\mu_2,\ldots,\mu_n$. That is, 
   $$v=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iw_i+\sum_{j=1}^n\mu_jv_j.$$
   Hence $\alpha$ generates $V$.

By checking the above two steps, we conclude that $\alpha$ is a basis for $V$, and therefore $V$ is finite-dimensional.